# Zend 2 Best Practice - Service Locator out side of Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Im new to Zend 2 and have this situation. Would like to know whats the best way to handle the situation.

Inside the Application module i have these classes

```
namespace Application\Foo;

class Base {
    protected $this->services; //service locator
    public function myFunc() {
        //needs service locator here
        $this->services;
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Application\Foo;

class A extends Base {
    //can have some method that uses $this->services;
}
```

---

```
namespace Application\Foo;

class B extends Base {

}
```

---

As you can see i need the service locator inside my Base class. and then i want to use the A,B... extended classes in my controllers.

Thanks in advice

---

**Update**

According to jmleroux's suggestion i updated the code to look like this

```
namespace Application\Foo;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Base implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
    protected $this->services; //service locator

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->services;
    }


    public function myFunc() {
        //needs service locator here
        $this->services;
    }
}
```

module.conf.php

```
service_manager => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'my_ser' => 'Application\Foo\Base'
    )
)
```

in my controller

```
$this->serviceLocator->get('my_ser');
```

returns the base class with service locator loaded

now my question is how to get my extended classes(A, B...) with the service locator loaded. since

```
$x = new \Application\Foo\A();
```

does not have the service locator loaded. do i have to add all my extended classes to module config as **invokables**? or is there a better alternative.

Thanks again.

---

**Update 2**

Thanks all (@jmleroux specially) for the support. Found these solutions and im adding them here thinking it will help some one else

***NOTE: Just a general idea. namespaces and class names are not accurate***

Solution 1 (recommended) - with ServiceLocatorAwareInterface / ServiceLocatorAwareTrait for php 5.4+

each class implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and add it to the service manager

```
namespace Application\Foor;

class A implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
protected $services;

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
    $this->services = $serviceLocator;
}

public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->services;
    }
}

class B implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
}
```

module.conf.php (or inside the Module getServiceConfig() function )

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'my_ser_a' => 'Application\Foo\A',
        'my_ser_b' => 'Application\Foo\B',
        ......
    )
)
```

call the service by name inside controllers

---

Solution 2 - with AbstractFactoryInterface

create a factory class

```
class MyFac implements AbstractFactoryInterface {
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName) {
        if (class_exists($requestedName)){ \\eg. check Application\Foo\A exists
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName) {
        $class = new $requestedName;   \\eg. creates an instance of Application\Foo\A
        $class->setServiceLocator($locator); \\make sure your class has this method 
        return new $class;
    }
}
```

module.conf.php (or inside the Module getServiceConfig() function )

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Application\Foo\MyFac'
    )
)
```

in controllers call

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Foo\A');
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the purpose of `Base` is just to provide a service locator, then don't use it. Especially if you are under PHP 5.4, you just have to implement the interface and use the `ServiceLocatorAwareTrait` and declare classes A and B as invokables. If you really want to centralize instantiation, you can also use an `AbstractFactory`

Comment: To answer your new question if you want the service locator injected then you have to have all the subclasses as invokables and loaded through the service manager. If you just instantiate them with new then it isn't going to work even if the parent is an invokable.

Comment: Thanks all, for my current situation using the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface seems like the best option. @jmleroux just for future references i would like to know how to implement AbstractFactory can you show/point me to a good example.

Comment: This post is quite clear : https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/tag/abstract-factory-in-zf2/

Comment: Thanks. thats post helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the service locator, your base class need to be declared as an invokable service implementing [ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.php)

If you are on PHP 5.4+, you can use [ServiceLocatorAwareTrait.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceLocatorAwareTrait.php)

Comment: Thanks. i've updated the code. please check it when you get a chance.